# Notice: Undefined index: appointDate

Tags: php, undefined-index

Getting Undefined index error on `appointDate` when running the code shown below:

```
$searchData = mysqli_query($connectme, "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE caseNo = '".$caseNo."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchData);
//Fix date for entry to form to day,month,year for display purposes only
$dateFixYear = substr($row['appointDate'], 0,4);
$dateFixMonth = substr($row['appointDate'], 5,2);
$dateFixDay = substr($row['appointDate'], 8,2);
$dateFixed = $dateFixDay . "/" . $dateFixMonth . "/" . $dateFixYear;
$row['appointDate'] = $dateFixed;
```

I would like to find the error in the code rather than ignoring it using `-`

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `appointDate` and `appointdate` in a loop, are two different animals and it may be a letter-case issue.

Comment: Please show the structure of the registration table. Its likely it does not have a row called appointDate